# TypeError in python code

Tags: python-2.7, typeerror

Recently while learning about functions, i defined a function which returned the cube of the number that the user entered. Also i defined another function that checks if the number is divisible by three and then cubes it. This is the code

```
    def cube(number):
        return number*number*number
    def by_three(number):
       if number%3 == 0:
          return cube(number)
   else:
    return False 
   number = raw_input("Enter any number\n")
   cube(number)
   by_three(number)
   print cube(number)
   print by_three(number)
```

After defining the functions I called the functions. Now when i run the program the input part( where the user inputs a number) works fine but after that i get an error as follows :

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "python", line 10, in <module>
    File "python", line 2, in cube
 TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'unicode'
```

Note that there is no indentation error. Since it is my first time asking a question i might have created the code blocks and not aligned the code properly. It is perfectly indented in my original script. :p

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input()` returns a string.

You need to wrap it in order to use the result as an integer:

```
int(raw_input())
```